# CentOS GUI problem using Gnome

Tags: centos, gnome, gui, interface

For some reason lately when I try to set the date using the interface, or simply install a .rpm by double clicking the dialog that should prompt me to input my passowrd just shakes like it has a bug. The dialog window that shakes has the title

```
"Authenticate"
Privileges are required to change the system time/install software/etc

Ann application is attempting to perform an action that requires privileges. 
Authentication as the super user is required to perform this action

Authenticat Failure
```

And I have to options: `Cancel` and `Authenticate`. The problem is this windows just shakes and disappears so I can't actually press the Authenticate button.

And after this window disappears I get a new one that says:

```
Failed to set the system time:
Not Authorized for action org.gnome.clockapplet.mechanism.settime
```

Why is this happening? A few days ago I was able to input my password and install software now this happens.

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for the *superuser* (root) password, not yours. And ths "shaking" is the way it shows that the entered password didn't match. Try with that one. Check that you can log in as root. Check that you can log in as yourself, check that you can `su` to root.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old bug look at this, maybe affect you  -> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=858873

one solution is:
run system-config-date as super user and change the date and localtime.

I hope it is useful